# mysql - why this subquery on WHERE clauses works?

Tags: mysql, sql

my movie table is here,

```
title        year length incolor studioName producerC#

Avengers        2012    142 1   Marvel      12345
First Avenger   2011    123 1   Marvel      38664 
Justice League  2017    121 1   DC          11223 
Man of Steel    1925    142 1   DC          38664 
Man of Steel    2013    142 1   DC          11223 
Ted             2012    106 1   Universal   87654 
Toy Story 3     2010    102 1   Pixar       23456
```

and i want find “the titles that have been used for two or more movies.”

the answer is 'Man of Steel' because this movie's year is 1925, 2013 so it used twice.

and my query is here.

```
select distinct movie.title 
from movie, (select * from movie) as temp
where temp.title = movie.title 
    AND (temp.year != movie.year OR temp.length != movie.length OR temp.studioName != movie.studioName);
```

as respect, the reult is `Man of Steel` what i want.

but i don't understand difference of temp, movie.

**both two table has perfectly same value**, so `temp.title = movie.title` should be `select title from movie;`

and `temp.year != movie.year` should be null because `temp.year != movie.year` is same of `select year from movie where movie.year != movie.year`

but result is  'Man of Steel'  and i can't understand what i missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query, both Temp and Movie are the exact same tables and the purpose of that join in other terms `SELF JOIN` is to match two movie titles while at least one of the other characteristic differs it can be Year, Length Or Studio Name. That's why it is given in the `WHERE` statement with a not equal notation in `OR` Condition.

Comment: oh, now i understand perfectly. because tables that on FROM clauses are producted .

Comment: Yes, If this answer helped you can select this as your accepted answer cheers :)

Comment: The reason why there are two results is because `m1.year = 2013, m2.year = 1925  and m1.year = 1925, m2.year = 2013`

Comment: Yes, simply you are joining only when there is a non-matching value in other columns except the movie title. So you get two combinations as you indicated with the Year column.

Answer (score 3):

Your current query is suboptimal.  You should rewrite it using explicit joins, in this case, an explicit self-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    m1.title
FROM movie m1
INNER JOIN movie m2
    ON m1.title = m2.title
WHERE
    m1.year <> m2.year OR m1.length <> m2.length OR m1.studioName <> m2.studioName;
```

The logic here is to consider every pair of movies which share the same title, but do *not* share either the year, length, or studio name.  That is, find all movies titles such that another movie exists with the same title, but one or more of the other fields differ.

There is another way to write your query using aggregation by movie title:

```
SELECT title
FROM movie
GROUP BY title
HAVING
    MIN(year) <> MAX(year) OR
    MIN(length) <> MAX(length) OR
    MIN(studioName) <> MAX(studioName);
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but in this homework, we can't use `join, group by` that will be treat next time. and my question's summary is `why m1.t1 != m1.temp ?` when subquery `(select * from m1) as temp`

Comment: You currently _are_ already doing a join, an implicit one.  Implicit joins are generally viewed as bad practice, so you might want to pass this message on to your instructor.